# Refresh two listviews when OnClick

Tags: android, listview, refresh

I have two listviews, in my Activity (fragment). I want to refresh the lists when the "tick" of friend request are clicked.

My code of the OnClick is all of that:

```
     viewHolder_solicituds.boto_aceptar
                                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        String nom_aceptat = solicituds.get(viewPosition).getName();
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Nom aceptat"+nom_aceptat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        SharedPreferences dades_login = context.getSharedPreferences("perfil", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        String id = dades_login.getString("id", "");
                                        String[] params= {id, nom_aceptat};

                //HERE I ADD FRIEND IN SERVER 
                PASSING THE PARAMS TO AN ASYNCTASK
                                        new AfegirAmic().execute(params); 

                //HERE I CREATED A RUNNABLE, I DONT KNOW WHY.. BUT I THINK IT WAS GOOD.

                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {

        //IN THIS CALLS I UPDATE THE LISTS FROM THE SERVER 
       //(WITH NEW FRIENDS ADDED AND ALL THE DATA REFRESHED)
                                                obtenir_solicituds();
                                                obtenir_amics();

//HERE I SET THE ADAPTER ANOTHER TIME, 
//AND NOTIFY DATA SET CHANGED FROM EVERY LISTVIEW TOO.                      

                        listView_Solicituds.setAdapter(adapter_solicitud);
                                                adapter_solicitud.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                listView_Amics.setAdapter(adapter);
                                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            }
                                        });
```

[image]

Comment: And whats wrong with your code? Where is the problem?

Comment: I want that, when I click to the Tick button, the listviews refresh with the new lists..

Comment: Just add your new friend to your list that is handled by your adapter and redraw your activity.

Comment: how to redraw my activity?